# Joomla access control and modified index.php

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, access-control

I'm working with a Joomla site, whose index.php file has been modified to alter the default access control behaviour. Bearing in mind this is Joomla 1.5, this line:

```
$mainframe->authorize($Itemid);
```

has been wrapped in some conditional code that looks up the remote IP and doesn't call `authorize()` if the IP is within a whitelisted range [*]. This is to allow seamless access to certain resources without logging in.

Although I'm new to Joomla development, I'm guessing this isn't the *best* way of doing that. For one, it probably means re-patching index.php in the event of a future Joomla upgrade. What's the best alternative approach to intercepting the authentication check?

[*] This is another mystery: the IP management takes place on the front-end via a component called 'IP filters'. There's a totally empty directory at `components/com_ipfilter`, but a more featureful-looking one at `administrator/components/com_ipfilter`. The component stores data in a table named `kip_filters` (why the 'k'?) and the authorUrl listed in the component's manifest file goes to a spammy-looking like pharma page. All quite worrying ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a system plugin which would not require hacking any files. There are quite a few system events that you can use to trigger your plugin and do your IP test, then determine whether to continue displaying the page or redirecting the visitor to some sort of warning page.

Take a look at the documentation on system events - http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System

--- More detail ---

Looking at the API execution order, the call to `authorize()` is going to happen no matter what (http://docs.joomla.org/API_Execution_Order). Since the default behavior is to call `authorize()` you are going to have to trick it into returning a positive response.

Your plugin should be triggered by `onAfterInitialise` and you should manipulate `JUser`. When you call `authorize()` the functions needs a user id which it gets from the JUser object and the `getuser()` function. All you need to do is create a user with the permissions you want, then have the plugin set the user ID so that `authorize()` returns true.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment, these are the relevant bits in index.php: `$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise'); ... $mainframe->route(); ... if (ip address not in whitelist) { $mainframe->authorize($Itemid); } ...` so I guess the system plugin you suggest would react to the `onAfterInitialise` event. Does that order of operation make sense, bearing in mind the call to `$mainframe->route()` ?

Comment: You can probably take much of the code and stick it in the plugin. Here's a tutorial on writing plugins - http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5

Comment: sure, but bits of that - i.e. `mainframe->route()` - are in the index.php file within the joomla distribution. I'd like to keep that file exactly as it should be, remove all the hacked changes, and ensure the custom code is in a completely separate place - i.e. in a plugin, as you suggest. I just need to be sure the event is an appropriate hook for this functionality. I guess the easiest way is to try it and see; please let me know if that's still unclear, and I'll edit the original question.

Comment: OK, reading the code again, it looks as though I can hook this into the `onAfterRoute` event and maintain the existing logic. I'm going to give this a go with a system plugin, then return and accept your answer :)

Comment: Right, it's a bit more complicated that I thought/hoped. Although I can abstract most of the functionality into a plugin, there's the tricky issue of the call to `$mainframe->authorize()` that remains in the default index.php. That's one line to hack, which is much better than before, but still not ideal. As I see it, the only alternative (since the authorize() behaviour is deeply ingrained in the core code) is to subclass JSite, but that's starting to get a BIT hardcore ...

Comment: Ok, this is going to get a little tricky since the default behavior is to call `$mainframe->authorize()`. You will have to trick the system in to authorizing a user instead. Your plugin should be triggered by `onAfterInitialise` and you should manipulate JUser. When you call `authorize()` the functions needs a user id which it gets from the JUser object and the `getuser()` function. All you need to do is create a user with the permissions you want, then have the plugin set the user ID so that `authorize()` returns true.

Comment: That's great info, thanks. I'm going to accept this answer and give you the bounty, but it would be nice if you could edit it and include some of this comment detail. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For the security problems you can use these steps and i will give you a good ip filter component as well :

First of all this is the most important component you can have for joomla : 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/16363
it gives you the most important ways to avoid any hacking or spamming or php bugs and also provide a very fast upgrade for your joomla site :) also it offering a IP Blacklisting manager which is a complete solution for your problem.

Hope this post will give someone a light !
Regards,
Raeed Rabie

Comment: Thanks. I don't really think there are any 'security' issues, just an obsolete component which probably wasn't very well put together in the first place. All I'm really after is a 'hook' for intercepting access control and modifying its behaviour. Do you know what provides the default access control in joomla?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise changing your table prefix from `jos_` to something random, like `hsfdaghadfg_`

You can also [relocate your configuration file](http://docs.joomla.org/Moving_sensitive_files_outside_the_web_root) for extra security.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't really a security issue. When I said "hacked" in the title, I was using it in the sense of 'changed in a slightly ad-hoc manner' as opposed to the layman meaning of 'cracked'. My bad; title updated.